# Is it possible for two classes to be data members of each other mutually?

Tags: java

Is it possible for a class A to be a field of another class B and at the same time, for class B to be a field of Class A?

I have a scenario where I have two classes: Match and Venue. I'm not sure whether to have the Venue as a data member of Match or the other way around or have each of them as a data member of the other, if Java permits that.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt it can be achieved by object construction time, which causes cyclic dependency. First create classA and classB objects and assign the mutual reference by using `setter`.

Comment: @rajuGT: make it an answer.

Comment: @rajuGT it can be done in the constructor. The A constructor can create a B and pass `this` to B's constructor.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, only if you pass all required parameters(of `B`) to constructor `A` which is more messy code and looks ugly I feel. It is applicable only if it is **no-arg** constructor.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** it is possible, but I doubt it can be achieved during object construction time, which causes *cyclic dependency*.

First create `classA` and `classB` objects and assign the mutual reference by using `setter` of each objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java actually supports cyclic dependencies between classes. So what you are asking is achievable but as the other answer pointed out it would cause some problems at construction time. I mean one constructor calling another might cause an overflow error. So instead you can do something like.

```
Match match = new Match();
Venue venue = new Venue();
match.setVenue(venue);
venue.setMatch(match);
```

In view of Garbage collection, If Match and Venue were to be referenced to each other and not by any other objects then they would be in a state of isolation ie Island of Isolation. They won't be eligible for garbage collection. I hope this helps.